# Will 2x10 13'6" span support outdoor bbq?

Tags: deck, span-tables

I am building a deck and will have 2x10 joists.  I want to put a BBQ that unfortunately will run parallel with the joists, so the last two joists will support the full weight of the BBQ distributed across 10'?  The span of the joists are 13' 6" between the header and supporting beam.  The outer rim will be doubled 2x10s.  My overestimate of the BBQ is that it will weight 2000-2200lbs.  Will the current joists support the weight?  If I double the 2nd joist, will that help?  Does that effectively support twice the weight or is that not how that works?  Should an additional post be added mid-span?

Comment: I don't know about decks, but my house uses 2x10 joists over a span of about that long without any problems.

Comment: Is your BBQ more like a BBQ pit? Bricked in, or something similar, and not moveable? At that weight, I assume it's not a standalone unit... You may be better off building the desk around the BBQ pit, or at the very least you'll need some structure directly underneath it (think how bathtubs are installed, and realize your BBQ weighs as much as 2 or 3 or 4 full tubs!).

Comment: It is more of a outdoor kitchen than BBQ pit.  It will be framed, covered with durrock and brick veneer.  It is easier to find the max span of a 2x10 but not the max load.  Also does doubling the 2x10 double the max load?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, two 2x10's spanning 13'-6" will support 2,200 lbs.  Grade of lumber can be No. 2 & better of typical framing lumber, like Hem.-Fir...it need not be Doug. Fir-Larch. In fact, each 2x10 will support 1,200 lbs.

To be clear, spans are measured as "clear spans". That is to say, from face of support to face of support. Also, if your BBQ is located in the middle of the span so that people can stand around the BBQ, then there will be an additional "Live Load" acting on the joists. This assumes the BBQ extends from support to support.

By the way, the code doesn't require blocking until you use 2x12's. However, for this "concentrated" load, I'd use blocking. (Yes, I know, technically, it's not a concentrated load, because it extends from support to support. However, it could be considered "concentrated" because it's resting on only 2 joist, not over multi-joists, like in a large space (room).)

If the joists rest on a beam, then secure the joists to the beam with a clip. If they "hang" on a beam, make sure the hangers are rated for the load, because you're approaching the joists maximum load. The joists need a minimum of 1 1/2" bearing at each end.

You didn't ask, but don't forget to install seismic deck straps (or rods) at about 20' oc. This is new to the 2014 code for all decks.

Re: your question about doubling joists...will that double the allowable supporting load...yes, that is how it works.

By the way, you reference a 10' space. Shouldn't that be 13'-6" space (span), or are you referring to the distance in the other direction. However, to me, that doesn't seem relevant because it doesn't contribute load to the 2x10 joists supporting the BBQ, right?

Comment: Oh, do you live where there's snow? That could change everything. If so, does it last longer than 7 days, longer than 1 month, or longer than 3 months?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  We do get snow except for the last two years.  Snow never lasts long here.  Comes and in a few days it is gone.  Occasionally we get hit with a blizzard but it has been a decade or so but the possibility is there.

Comment: The BBQ is at the end of the deck so anyone standing around will actually be supported by an adjacent joist.

The joists will rest on the beam on one end and hang from the header on the other, so I will check the hangers.  The BBQ will basically be sitting on 4 2x10s.

I'll look into the seismic straps. I'm not sure they are required in my area but probably still a good idea.

10' is the span of the BBQ.  13'6" is the span of the 2x10 between the header and supporting beam.  I only mentioned it because all the weight of the BBQ will be distributed across 10' of the 13' span.

Comment: Last thing I was curious about.  Since there are four 2x10s, 2 on the perimeter and two for the first interior joist, the load would be equally distributed across all of them.  That would mean only 550lb on each which is well under the 1200lbs.  Am I correct?

Comment: If the BBQ is close enough to the edge that the double 2x10 will help support it, then you are in great shape...wit or without snow loading.    For the seismic anchors, I'd use something like Simpson's DTY2SS if your beams are pressure treated and DTT2Z if it's made out of cedar or Redwood. AND you only need one at about 20' oc. to attach the deck to the structure of the house.

Comment: Oops...that DTY2SS should read DTT2SS.